Is there an English word to describe selecting words that have two different meanings to fit the context?
a Christian Science monitor article describing a swimmer's journey
The title of the article reads "A stroke of dignity at..." , referring to an Olympic swimming event. How to interpret this?
In swimming there are breaststrokes, sidestrokes etc. and in writing we have strokes to write or draw something.
Can we also have, then, a stroke of disgrace, for instance, for swimming events with negative news?

Arguably a duplicate: Is there a single word for speech with a double -meaning?. ['Pun' a given answeer.]

It would be unusual to say a stroke of disgrace; we usually have strokes of feats and fortune. Stroke of genius, stroke of luck, etc. Even a stroke of dignity is a bit odd.

To pun -> to make a pun
OED

1. intransitive. To make a pun or puns; to play on words. Also with on or upon. Also figurative.
1992 His first Times Sunday puzzle punned on composers, with answers
like ‘Bizet signal’, ‘Handel with care’, ‘Haydn go seek’. New York
Times Magazine 16 February 39/3

